# How to configure SSRS (SQL Server 2012) to run on a different instance, but same server as SharePoint

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs

I have an instance of SQL Server 2012 running on Windows 2008R2 along side another instance of SQL Server 2012 that is running SharePoint (I think it is SharePoint 2010).

When I try to access the `http://localhost/Reports_<InstanceName>` I am getting:

1. A certificate warning (which I proceed through - I don't really care about this - its a dev machine)
2. The following text: `Cannot connect to the configuration database.`

Google says that that error message is SharePoint related so I am inclined to think that SharePoint is highjacking the SSRS request.

Is there a configuration I can make to SSRS or something else (IIS maybe??) that will let me access the Report Server?

**Note**: I can connect to Reporting Services through SSMS just fine.

Comment: Seeing as you assume that SharePoint is the issue, can you actually connect to the SharePoint instance running on the server? Does SharePoint pick up your request? I am surprised you are receiving a certificate warning for a non-SSL request. Does your URI get rewritten to HTTPS? A screen shot of the certificate error message could be beneficial in answering your question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure of your version of Sharepoint? I thought SP2010 could not run on SQLS2012 but 2008 and 2008R2.

With which machine do you try to access the report server ?

If you have SP and SSRS native mode installed on the same machine you will get error due to the address (SP and Report Server use the same). You can change the report server address in the Reporting services configuration manager (Start, Microsft SQL server 2012, Configuration Tools) and Report Manager URL tab.

Answer (score 0):

Have you definitely setup the ReportServer db and started the service ?

When you run Reporting Services Configuration Manager, connect to the non Sahrepoint instance, on the Report Server Status screen does it show your ReportServer db name and show status as running ?